# VPN Connection site to site Alibaba Virtual Private Cloud

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Anyone have idea why "Phase 1 of IKE Tunnel Negotiation Failed" comes up when I try to use  IPsec method to establish connection between on-prem and Alibaba Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKE negotiates the IPSec security associations, called SAs, between two endpoints. Each security association has parameters that must match on both sides. Verify that you have configured the phase 1 policy with the same parameters for Encryption, Hash, Diffie-Hellman Group and Authentication.

Note: You have left a lot of important details out of your question.

Answer (score 0):

the following recommend for you

IKE profile settings

Set the lifetime to a value configured on the Alibaba Cloud side between 900 and 28,800 (default) seconds.
Set the encryption algorithm to either AES-128 or AES-256.
Set the hashing algorithm to either SHA-1 or SHA-2(256).
Set the Pseudo Random Function (PRF) to the same algorithm as the hashing algorithm.
Enable one of the following Diffie-Hellman groups: 2, 14-18, 22, 23, or 24.
IPsec profile settings

Set the lifetime to a value configured on the Alibaba Cloud side between 900 and 3,600 (default) seconds, with less than phase 1 lifetime.
Set the encryption algorithm to either AES-128 or AES-256.
Set the hashing algorithm to either SHA-1 or SHA-2(256).
Enable perfect forward secrecy (PFS) using one of the following Diffie-Hellman groups: 2, 5, 14-18, 22, 23, or 24.